# Unknown issue with Discord.js and ytdl, completely skips playing audio

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, discord, discord.js

One of the commands I have for my Discord bot is to play a predefined music clip in the current user's voice channel. The bot can connect, but rather than playing the song, it instantaneously leaves. I've tried using both `connection.playStream` as well as `connection.playFile`, and both seem to return the same (lack of) output. Am I missing some sort of dependency or is my code just written incorrectly? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 1};

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Login Success');
});

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '$vaporwave') {
    if (!message.guild) return;
    if(message.member.voiceChannel) {
      message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
        console.log("joined channel");
        //const stream = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cU8HrO7XuiE', { filter : 'audioonly' });
        const dispatcher = connection.playFile('./mcp420.mp3');
        //const dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream, streamOptions);
        dispatcher.on("end", end => {
          console.log("left channel");
          message.member.voiceChannel.leave();
        });
      }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  }
});
```

- NPM v4.6.1
- Node.js v8.9.1
- FFMPEG v3.2.8-1

Answer (score 0):

By using `dispatcher.on('error', console.error);`, I was able to discover that `sodium` had not been installed on my host machine, and was causing error during file playback. Working normally now.